# How to group by in ManyToMany relationships in Django?

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-queryset

I am creating a web application with Django and I have some problems using its ORM to make queries.
I have these models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Song(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="songs")
ratings = models.ManyToManyField(Country, through='Rating')

class Rating(models.Model):
rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
country_id = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
song_id = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

A Country rates many Songs (with ratings 1-10), and a Song can be rated by many Countries, so  there's a ManyToMany relationship between these models through the Rating table.
I am making a query to get the number of 10 points a Song has received, but I don't know how. To do that, I tried this query:

```
result = Rating.objects.filter(rating=10).values('song_id').annotate(ten_points = Count('rating'))
```

I read Django documentation and I understood that values() method is like group by clause in SQL, but it doesn't work because this query returns a queryset of dictionaries like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'song_id': 1, 'ten_points': 1}, {'song_id': 2, 'ten_points': 1}, {'song_id': 2, 'ten_points': 1}, {'song_id': 3, 'ten_points': 1}, {'song_id': 3, 'ten_points': 1}
```

Why am I getting different dictionaries with the same key and value 1, instead of a dictionary with the key and the value the total number of ten points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.order_by(…)` to force grouping, so:

```
result = Rating.objects.filter(rating=10).values(
    'song_id'
).annotate(ten_points=Count('rating')).order_by('song_id')
```

But in this specific case, it might make more sense to annotate the `Song`s:

```
Song.objects.filter(
    rating__rating=10
).annotate(
    ten_points=Count('rating')
)
```

This will only include `Song`s that have at least *one* `Rating` record with `rating=10`. If you want to annotate *all* `Song`s, you can use:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Song.objects.annotate(
    ten_points=Count('rating', filter=Q(rating__rating=10))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It worked perfectly. But I have a question: Why do I need to use order_by to force grouping in the first solution that you proposed? I thought order_by method is only to order the rows depending on an field.

Comment: @JesúsRoldánCadena: yes, that's a peculiarity, I don't know why they implemented that through the `.order_by(...)` clause. But you need to do this to force grouping on the values.